# Prove that the function $f(n)=n^3+(\frac{n}{2^n})^5$ satisfies some property (where $n\in\Bbb{N}$)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am stucked at this problem:

---

Prove that the function $f(n)=n^3+(\frac{n}{2^n})^5$ satisfies the property (where $n\in\Bbb{N}$):

**there exists** $c\in(0,1)$ and $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that **for all** $n_0\leq n\in\Bbb{N}$ we get $f(\frac{n}{2})\leq c f(n)$.

---

I've tried several values of $c$ (For example $\frac{3}{4}$) but I failed to prove it.

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: Hint: try estimating the limit of $a_n = \frac{f(\frac{n}{2})}{f(n)}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$, using $f(n) \ge n^3$ to give an upper bound for $a_n$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{n^5}{2^{5n}} = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{n^5}{2^{\frac{5}{2}n}} = 0$$

so

$$cf(n) - f(\frac{n}{2}) = cn^3 + c\frac{n^5}{2^{5n}} - \frac{n^3}{8} - \frac{1}{2^5} \frac{n^5}{2^{\frac{5}{2}n}}$$

$$= (c-\frac{1}{8}) n^3 + n^5\left( \frac{c}{2^{5n}} - \frac{1}{2^5}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{5}{2}n}} \right) \sim (c-\frac{1}{8})n^3$$

So for $c>\frac{1}{8}$ and $n$ big enough, this is positive and you have the result

Answer (score 1):

try putting $f(m)\leq cf(2m),$and so you obtained $\frac{f(m)}{f(2m)}\leq c$ prove that the limit $\frac{f(m)}{f(2m)}, m \rightarrow \infty$ exist and that this limit  some number in $(0,1)$ call $c$ to this limit and by the definition of limits you get the answer to your question.